# header wrong for first page of bibliography

Tags: bibtex, fancyhdr

Here is some sample code partially taken from other examples here. With this code, a page number is erroneously shown in the center footer for the first page of the bibliography. This is not the style I have defined. This same problem would occur for the Index, but is fixed by the \indexsetup call. Presumably there's a similar fix for the bibliography. What is it?

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{darwin1859origin,
  title={On the origin of species: facsimile of the first edition},
  author={Darwin, Charles},
  year={1859},
  publisher={LONDON: JOHN MURRAY, ALBEMARLE STREET.}
}
\end{filecontents}
% copied and modified from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356094/index-and-fancyhydr
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[body={110mm, 185mm}, headheight=55pt]{geometry}  
\usepackage{imakeidx}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeindex[columnsep=20pt,columnseprule]

\indexsetup{
  othercode={%
    \thispagestyle{index}%
  }
}

\fancypagestyle{index}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[RO]{\textit{Index}\hspace{1em}\thepage}%
  \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage\hspace{1em}\textit{Index}}%
} 

\fancypagestyle{paper}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}%
  \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}%
}


\pagestyle{paper}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-8]

\cite{darwin1859origin}

\count255=0
\loop\ifnum\count255<130 \advance\count255 1
\expandafter\index\expandafter{\romannumeral\count255 }
\repeat

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{index}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The bibliography is a chapter, and the default in LaTeX, at least for the `book` documentclass, is to use the `plain` pagestyle for the first page of a chapter. So the easiest solution is to redefine the `plain` pagestyle to be the same as `paper`.

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}[paper]{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
```

Of course this would also change the first pagestyle for all following chapters, but in your case that's only the Index and you have already taken care of that.

In case you would like the header to be slightly different e.g. containing the word 'Bibliography', then put the proper command, like `\fancyhead` between the curly braces in the first line.